# Iterate over table row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm studying the psychology of Rock Paper Scissors using Excel. I am saving the games in a table named *Games* with columns **Player0** (what player 0 used), **Player1** and **Winner** (can be 0, 1 or T for Tie).

[image]

I want to know how many wins were made using each option(1) (table on the left) so I need to iterate over every row in the table to check if the win was made using, for example, rock.

I tried using the following COUNTIF for rock

```
=COUNTIF( Games,   IF( IF( $D = 0, $B, IF( $D = 1, $C, FALSE ) ) = "R", TRUE, FALSE ) )
```

but I can't figure out what to use to access other columns in the same row (instead of the $D, $B, $C).

The expected count is:

```
Rock Win - 3
, Paper Win - 0
, Scissor Win - 7
, Tie - 12
```

(1) Example: A Rock Win would be a Rock vs Scissor match.

Comment: @pnuts I tried using that, but I'm having trouble in refering the collumns in the same row. For example, imagine it starts in the first row, how can I refer to the Winner collumn in the same row?

Comment: difficult to suggest an idea until you show the data

Comment: Thanks @GowthamShiva , I just reformulated my question to include an image.

Comment: can you update the expected output too? the rock win, paper win and scissor win

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you where asking but I think I fixed it. @GowthamShiva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rock Win:

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C,"<>T",A:A,"R",B:B,"S")+COUNTIFS(C:C,"<>T",A:A,"S",B:B,"R")
```

Paper Win:

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C,"<>T",A:A,"R",B:B,"P")+COUNTIFS(C:C,"<>T",A:A,"P",B:B,"R")
```

Scissor Win:

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C,"<>T",A:A,"P",B:B,"S")+COUNTIFS(C:C,"<>T",A:A,"S",B:B,"P")
```

Tie:

```
=COUNTIF(C:C,"T")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

in I4 use the following

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C,"R",E:E,"0")+COUNTIFS(D:D,"R",E:E,"1")
```

Change the R to S and then P accordingly for the ppapper or siccor wins

in I7 use the following:

```
=COUNTIF(E:E,"T")
```

and in I8 use the following:

```
=COUNTA(E:E)-1
OR
=SUM(I4:I7)
```

The -1 one is to account for the header rows.

to get your percentages use the following in J4 and copy down:

```
=I4/$I$8
```

Caveat:  all cells below your last entry need to be blank.

Proof of Concept

[image: POC]

### bonus

For determining winner results in column E:

`=IF(C2=D2,"T",IF(OR(AND(C2="R",D2="S"),AND(C2="P",D2="R"),AND(C2="S",D2="P")),0,1))`

### ALTERNATIVE

#### (BUT NOT PREFERRED!

Since there are multiple ways of doing things, here is an option that will get your counts for column I by doing array like calculations without being an array:

For I4 to I 6 respectively

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$23=LEFT($H4))*($D$2:$D$23="s")+($C$2:$C$23="s")*($D$2:$D$23=LEFT($H4)))

=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$23=LEFT($H5))*($D$2:$D$23="r")+($C$2:$C$23="r")*($D$2:$D$23=LEFT($H5)))

=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$23=LEFT($H6))*($D$2:$D$23="p")+($C$2:$C$23="p")*($D$2:$D$23=LEFT($H6)))
```

For I7 you have the choice of working with your column E results using:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($E$2:$E$23=LEFT($H7)))
```

Or by passing your column E results and using:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(C2:C23=D2:D23))
```

To get your total matchs, either sum the results above or use

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(C2:C23<>""))
```

Now the reason for not using the array like operations is you do not want to go with full column references as it would add a lot of extra calculations for nothing.  The benefit is you can have information ie use the cells below your table with out having them throw your counts off.

Comment: Exactly what I intended to write :) +1